# TypeScript 2 definitions for Google Maps API

Tags: node.js, google-maps, express, mongoose, typescript2.0

I'm working with TypeScript 2, Node JS, Express 4 and MongoDB (with Mongoose as ORM) in Visual Studio 2015. I'm trying to install Google Maps API library, but I'm not having success.

I installed it with "npm install @google/maps" (https://www.npmjs.com/package/@google/maps) and the TypeScript 2 definitions with "npm install @types/googlemaps" (https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/googlemaps).

The problem is they have different names! (Both are the officials versions). So the compiler tell me "Cannot find module "@google/maps" when I write require("@google/maps").

I would be very gratefully if you could help me because I really need it for my project.

Thanks!

Comment: Hola Luciano! did you had lucky making this work?

Comment: Inspect all references of `@google/maps`. Where does it go?